# How to handle Async Local Storage with Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, local-storage

I am setting the expiry for a token in local storage, using the angular async local storage module.

```
import { AsyncLocalStorage } from 'angular-async-local-storage';

const expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());

this.localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt).subscribe(() => {});
```

I then have a function that is called when a user logs in, which checks to see if the token is still valid:

```
get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    let res;
    this.localStorage.getItem('expires_at')
        .subscribe((val) => {
            let expiresAt = JSON.parse(val);
            res = (expiresAt && this.loggedIn) ? (new Date().getTime() < expiresAt) : false;
        });

    return res;
}
```

The problem here is that localStorage.getItem() returns an Observable.
so when we call .subscribe on the observable, it is called asynchronously which means we don't block until the result is ready
so the code just goes straight through and executes the return res statement, which at this point res is undefined, as the code in the subscribe arrow function has not executed yet because the result is not ready.

So I need some advice on the best approach to solving this is?
One approach I thought of was to try and block until the result is ready, but that seems like an anti pattern given that we are using the ASYNC local storage module.
But maybe what I need is just a simple synchronous local storage module? Or is this considered bad practice?
Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Is this method `isAuthenticated()` in a service or in a component?

Comment: it is in a class, i.e. @Injectable export class Foo { ... isAuthenticated() } .  Does this make a difference as to how I should handle the async call?

Comment: Do you mind showing more of this file? `@Injectable` should be a service file not a component file.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: In your case I would go with synchronous localstorage solution.

Long story:

In situations like this (synchronous vs asynchronous) in Angular I always ended up with one of these two solutions:

1) Let isAuthenticated return Observable and map your localstorage observable to return true/false

```
get isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.localStorage.getItem('expires_at').pipe(
        map((val) => {
            let expiresAt = JSON.parse(val);
            let res = (expiresAt && this.loggedIn) ? (new Date().getTime() < expiresAt) : false;
            return res;
        })
    );
}
```

2) Go with synchronous solution like you proposed

What is best practice depends on situation. In my experience if you do it the observable-way you will end up with more code handling all the possible & impossible situations. Also all the dependencies on this code must be called asynchronously too (eg if you are logged in then send HTTP request and then render its response). If you want to handle these kind of things DRY and in services you will have to dig deeper into RxJS and its operators like MergeAll etc...

On the other way if you used synchronous solution, your code would be much simpler but in some cases your app could become uncomfortably slow ( imagine HTTP requests synchronous on slow mobile network).

So if you are getting just one small item just once from localStorage, you wouldn't see difference. On the other way this library gives you same interface for IndexedDb where max limit [could be 2Gb of data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria) so you can save there whole collections and then your app speed-up could be massive if you used async way.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your user already expects to waits for an asynchronous login to load, so you could chain your localStorage call to it with flatMap:

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<number> {
    return this.localStorage.getItem('expires_at')
    .map((val) => {
            let expiresAt = JSON.parse(val);
            return (expiresAt && this.loggedIn) ? (new Date().getTime() < expiresAt) : 0;
        });
}

yourLoginFunction()
.flatMap(loginRes => {
    return this.isAuthenticated()
})
.subscribe(res => {
    // handle accordingly
}
```

Note that `isAuthenticated()` can’t have type `boolean` or `Observable<boolean>` and return a timestamp. So I changed `false` to `0`.